# How to fix a loop through a Hashmap<int<arraylist>> assigning more values than expected

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

thank you in advance for your time!
I am working on a Fruchterman Reingold Graph creator, and I am stuck in what seems to be a very simple problem. Long story short, I want to initialize a Hashmap that contains an Integer key, that being, the vertex I am at, and a List of integers that are the x position and y position. The following code however places 8 instead of 2 position values instead of 2 per key. Any help or tip, is greatly appreciated!

```
package testing.ground;

import java.util.*;


public class TestingGround {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    Random ranx = new Random();
    Random rany = new Random();
    HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>> positions=new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int n = 3;
    int area = 1280*720;
    int vposx=0;
    int vposy=0;


    double k = 0.5*(Math.sqrt(area/n));
    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++){
        vposx=ranx.nextInt(1280)+1;
        vposy=rany.nextInt(720)+1;
        temp.add(vposx);
        temp.add(vposy);
        positions.put(i,temp);

    }
        System.out.println(positions);
}
}
```

The results are these

> {0=[1063, 102, 41, 391, 614, 418, 751, 599], 1=[1063, 102, 41, 391, 614, 418, 751, 599], 2=[1063, 102, 41, 391, 614, 418, 751, 599], 3=[1063, 102, 41, 391, 614, 418, 751, 599]}

The expected ones would be simply `0=[randomx,randomy], 2=[randomx,randomy] and so on`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a new `ArrayList` for each value of your `Map`:

```
for (int i=0; i<=n; i++){
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    vposx=ranx.nextInt(1280)+1;
    vposy=rany.nextInt(720)+1;
    temp.add(vposx);
    temp.add(vposy);
    positions.put(i,temp);
}
```

Otherwise, you are associating all the keys in your `Map` with the same value `List`.

Comment: If the `List` doesn't need to be resized. Then `Arrays.asList()` may aswell be used

Comment: Such a ridiculous oversight on my behalf. It completely fixed my issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Mark this answer as chosen one! @KrowCaw

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;

public class SomeTestingClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Random ranx = new Random();
Random rany = new Random();
HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>> positions=new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> temp = null;

int n = 3;
int area = 1280*720;
int vposx=0;
int vposy=0;


double k = 0.5*(Math.sqrt(area/n));
for (int i=0; i<=n; i++){
    vposx=ranx.nextInt(1280)+1;
    vposy=rany.nextInt(720)+1;
    **temp=new ArrayList<Integer>();** // this will solve your problem
    temp.add(vposx);
    temp.add(vposy);
    positions.put(i,temp);

}
    System.out.println(positions);
```

}
}